# Comparing time stamps in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Suppose if i declare 2 timestamp variable .
Lets say

```
DECLARE 

var_t1 timestamp :=null;
var_t1 timestamp :=null;
BEGIN 
---Suppose if i assign a timestamp to var_t1 . 

select some_date into var_t1 from sometable where id='some_id';

--IF(var_t2<>var_t2) , this will be always false .

IF(var_t1 <> var_t2 ) THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Inside if');

END IF;

END;
```

If any one variable is null, always if return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If any one variable is null, always if return false.

You are comparing a value with **NULL**. It is neither **TRUE** nor **FALSE**. It is a tri-valued logic, which is **unknown**.

- nothing is equal to null
- nothing is NOT equal to null

More meaningful code would be:

```
IF a <> b or (a is null and b is not null) or (a is not null and b is null)
THEN
```

**UPDATE** Adding an example.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    A NUMBER;
  3    b NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5    A    :=NULL;
  6    B    :=10;
  7    IF a <> b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NOT NULL) OR (a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NULL) THEN
  8      dbms_output.put_line('False');
  9    END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /
False

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Then how do we fix this issue ?

Comment: Using the syntax I gave as an example. Mention the NULL and NOT NULL conditions explicitly as OR conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there any easier way to resolve this , instead of multiple conditions ?

Comment: This is the safest way I know. You could use NVL though. Read for NVL function. Please mark it answered, would help others.

Comment: Or Coalesce() - ANSI compatible, more flexible, with short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addon to Lalit answer:

```
var_t1 <> var_t2 or var_t1 is null or var_t2 is null
```

is equivalent to

```
LNNVL(var_t1 = var_t2)
```

just shorter. But note, you can use `LNNVL` only in `WHERE` clause of an `SELECT`, not in PL/SQL `IF LNNVL()` (don't ask what is the reason for this limitation - I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

and for completeness' sake i will add a "NVL" solution

```
declare 
    yearone timestamp :=to_date('1','yyyy');
    var_t1 timestamp :=null;
    var_t2 timestamp :=sysdate;
begin 
    if nvl(var_t1, yearone) <> nvl(var_t2, yearone) then
        dbms_output.put_line('Inside if');
    end if;
end;
/
```